# Unwinding to view with search results controller active leaves black gap at top

Tags: ios, objective-c, ios8, uisearchcontroller

I have multiple view controllers which all use one class (we'll call it `searchClass` `<NSObject>`) I wrote that has a `UISearchController` for searching an external API. The user can tap the search icon and the search controller becomes active: `[_searchClass.searchController setActive:YES];` It uses its own table view controller (not the one in each of the view controllers, because they aren't all table view controllers).

In my case I make the search bar appear in the navigation bar. Search works great, the user can select a search result and tap it for a detail view. **The problem** is when the user goes back (unwinds) from the detail view to the search results, there is a black gap about 44 pts tall that appears briefly above the table view and below the navigation bar, and then disappears.

Here is my setup. In the view controller:

```
    self.definesPresentationContext = YES;
    _searchClass = [SearchClass new];
    _searchClass.navController = [self navigationController];
```

In the search class:

```
    _searchTableViewController = [[UIStoryboard storyboardWithName:@"MainStoryboard" bundle:[NSBundle mainBundle]] instantiateViewControllerWithIdentifier:@"searchTableViewController"];
    _searchTableViewController.tableView.delegate = self;
    _searchTableViewController.tableView.dataSource = self;
    _searchTableViewController.tableView.backgroundColor = [UIColor clearColor];
    _searchTableViewController.tableView.tableFooterView = [[UIView alloc] initWithFrame:CGRectZero];
    _searchTableViewController.tableView.tableHeaderView = [[UIView alloc] initWithFrame:CGRectZero];
    _searchTableViewController.definesPresentationContext = YES;

    _searchController = [[UISearchController alloc] initWithSearchResultsController:_searchTableViewController];
    _searchController.delegate = self;
    _searchController.hidesNavigationBarDuringPresentation = NO;

    _searchController.searchBar.delegate = self;
    _searchController.searchBar.searchBarStyle = UISearchBarStyleMinimal;
    _searchController.searchBar.showsCancelButton = YES;
    _searchController.searchBar.frame = CGRectMake(self.searchController.searchBar.frame.origin.x, self.searchController.searchBar.frame.origin.y, self.searchController.searchBar.frame.size.width, 44.0);
```

There are also the usual delegate methods for `UISearchBar` and `UISearchController`, and the code that displays the search bar, which uses an animation to replace the titleView of the navigation bar.

How do I get rid of that gap after unwinding back to the search results?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I found the solution, it's related to the `UINavigationBar`. For some reason setting the translucent property to `NO` seems to have caused this issue.

```
self.navigationBar.translucent = YES;
```

Setting it to `YES` (or omitting the line since it is the default) made it work properly. Since I still wanted to have the navigation bar be opaque, I did the following to make the nav bar translucent only during transitions, which seems to be where the issue lies:

```
- (void) viewWillDisappear:(BOOL)animated {
    [super viewWillDisappear:animated];
    self.navigationController.navigationBar.translucent = YES;
}

-(void) viewDidAppear:(BOOL)animated {
    [super viewDidAppear:animated];
    self.navigationController.navigationBar.translucent = NO;
}
```

Definitely seems like a genuine iOS bug to me.